# WPF Slider changing the position and number of Ticks

Tags: wpf, slider

I need to be able to change ticks on a slider and the following code seems to work only the first time its called. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
     private void ApplyTicks()
    {
        try
        {
            this.timeSlider.Ticks.Clear();

            if (this.ticks != null)
            {
                DoubleCollection tickMarks = new DoubleCollection();

                foreach (double tick in this.ticks)
                {
                    tickMarks.Add(tick);
                }

                if (tickMarks.Count <= 0)
                {
                    tickMarks.Add(0.0);

                }

                this.timeSlider.Ticks = tickMarks;
                log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("StreamCodersVideoPlayerControl.ApplyTicks").Debug("Ticks applied.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WPFMessageBox.Show("Error", e.Message);
            log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("StreamCodersVideoPlayerControl.ApplyTicks").Error("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code, how are you updating the ticks collection ?, and where are you calling the ApplyTicks() method, post more details

Comment: the the ticks collection is updated in other methods:   public void AddTick(double tick)
        {
            this.ticks.Add(tick);

            ApplyTicks();
        }

        public void RemoveTick(double tick)
        {
            this.ticks.Remove(tick);

            ApplyTicks();
        }